# how to get value from a complex soap response in php

Tags: php, xml, soap

I use

```
print "<br />\n Response: ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());
```

then I get this response from soap response:

```
Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAllCompaniesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetAllCompaniesResult><xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="PROD.CLIENTS" msprop:BaseTable.0="CLIENTS" msprop:BaseSchema="PROD"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="COMPANYNAME" msprop:BaseColumn="COMPANY1" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="CODE" msprop:BaseColumn="CODE" msprop:OraDbType="112" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet xmlns=""><PROD.CLIENTS diffgr:id="PROD.CLIENTS1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><COMPANYNAME> WSQ IMPLEMENT OEE FOR PRODUCTIVITY IMPROVEMENT (14042014) CIP</COMPANYNAME><CODE>5671</CODE></PROD.CLIENTS><PROD.CLIENTS diffgr:id="PROD.CLIENTS2" msdata:rowOrder="1"><COMPANYNAME>10DOLLARSCOMPANY</COMPANYNAME>
```

and etc. (it is a long response message)

I would like to get each name between the tag  but I couldn't figure out the structure of this output, an I also see the tag name has some special character like ":" or "." that make me confuse. Can you give me some help pls! Many thanks!

Comment: That responce is XML, so you need to use something like the simpleXML php extension to help you process it properly. [PHP Manual SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: I did some google of similar solution like that, but I don't know how it could apply for this case?

Comment: $client->__getLastResponse() returns an XML string. Read the manual, its available in multiple languages [PHP manual homepage](http://php.net/docs.php). I am not going to spend time writing it for you.

Comment: How do I process tag name like <diffgr:diffgram..> and <PROD.CLIENTS> is it a tag name or what ? This XML string doesn't look simple like the one in other examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, after looking around, test and test again...
Here is how:

```
$result = $client->__getLastResponse();
$doc = DOMDocument::loadXml($result);
$count =$doc->getElementsByTagName('COMPANYNAME')->length;
```

Hope it will help who with same issue with me. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the whole SOAP conform response with that method call. But you just want the part which is of interest for you. This is the return value of the SOAP function call:

According to the manual for [`SoapClient::__getLastResponse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php):

```
$client = SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$result = $client->SomeFunction();
echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
```

You may want to parse `$result` with `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result)`. It contains the data you want. While `$client->__getLastResponse()` contains the whole SOAP response not just the returned data of the `SomeFunction` SOAP-API call.

But to get you a more specific answer we have to see your PHP SOAP code.

Comment: The whole Soap response looks like have only one function "GetAllCompaniesResult". I tried: $values = $client->GetAllCompanies($parameters);$xml = $values->GetAllCompaniesResult; But it will returns many data belong to different fields, connected to each other.

Comment: You have to do then: 

`$values = $client->GetAllCompanies($parameters);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($values);`

Comment: So what's the plain content of `$values` then? (You know that you have to do a `var_dump($xml)` to see the content of the variable `$xml`, don't you?)

Comment: var_dump($value) shows: object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["GetAllCompaniesResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["schema"]=> string(761) "" ["any"]=> string(778325) " WSQ IMPLEMENT OEE FOR PRODUCTIVITY IMPROVEMENT (14042014) CIP567110DOLLARSCOMPANY5882 ...

Comment: This can't be. You should get an XML string as response AFAIK.

Comment: That is exactly what I get. If I do one more step: $xml = $values->GetAllCompaniesResult;print "<pre>\n"; print_r($xml); print "</pre>"; then I get: stdClass Object
([schema] => (newline here:) [any] =>  WSQ IMPLEMENT ..etc.

Comment: If I do: $xresult = htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()); then: var_dump($xresult); I will get: string(1062612) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap... and the whole result, we can load that and process from there. Is that more like what you want to put into load string xml ?

Comment: Okay and why do you can't work with the `stdClass` objects you get from the SOAP call?

Comment: Because I cannot recognize its structure. As mentioned in my question, I want to get out companyName, how to do so ?

Comment: I try to print out properties of that object but I cannot see any property. I use $properties = get_object_vars($xml);
print_r($properties); I only all values printed connected together.